# Is there any way to convert Excel template file to PDF in .NET Application?

Tags: c#

There are some complex template files in Excel format in the system, which are filled with data through the program. However, what I need is a PDF file.

One option is to use a third-party library or component that can perform the conversion. These libraries typically have a cost associated with them and They cannot be used due to procurement policy restrictions.

Another option is to use Microsoft Office Interop to automate the conversion of Excel files to PDF. This approach involves programmatically opening Excel, loading the template file, and then saving it as a PDF. However, this approach can be complex and I don't think this is the best solution.
**
Is there any service available on Azure that can be used for this, or are there any other recommended custom solutions?**

Comment: Do not use Office interop on a server. Really bad things can happen at the worst possible time https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

Comment: As @Flydog57 mentioned, I would stay awsy from using the Interop on a remote machine. There are plenty of public projects (I only looked on github) for this. Find one that suits your needs (license, api, language, etc)